# onAuthStateChanged and getRedirectResult returning null user after successful google login redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Somewhat randomly my login flow stops working for some users when using google as a login provider (possibly facebook too, unsure) on iOS. They are able to log in on desktop using google login with the same app bundle. I think this is happening for ~1/10 users.

After a user selects which google account to use, the google redirects back to my app. The `onAuthStateChange` triggers, but the user is null. This is after successfully "logging in" with google. I *think* this may have to do with users trying to use multiple auth providers and getting stuck in a weird state. I'm not receiving any error or console logs when this happens, it's as if it's a fresh page load instead of a redirect.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue using my own account until recently. I tried reverting back to earlier builds when the issue wasn't present for my account, with no luck. I'm now unable to log into my own app

in `UserProvider.tsx`:

```
firebaseConfig.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_API_KEY;
firebaseConfig.authDomain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN;
firebaseConfig.projectId = "redacted";
firebaseConfig.storageBucket = "redacted.appspot.com";
firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId = "redacted";
firebaseConfig.appId = "redacted";

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  popupRedirectResolver: browserPopupRedirectResolver,
  persistence: [indexedDBLocalPersistence, browserLocalPersistence, inMemoryPersistence],
  errorMap: debugErrorMap
});

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithRedirect(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  const handleUserCredential = async (result: UserCredential) => {
    if (result.user) {
      const additionalInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_ADDITIONAL_USER_INFO', data: {
          additionalInfo: additionalInfo,
        }
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_INITIATED' });
    const handleRedirectResult = async () => {
      alert("handling redirect result");
      const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
      alert(`redirect result: ${result}`);
      if (result) {
        handleUserCredential(result)
      }
    }

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user: User | null) => {
      alert(`on auth change fired: ${user}`);
      if (user) {
        // set the token now
        const token = await getIdToken(user);
        const refreshToken = async () => {
          return await getIdToken(user, true);
        }
        onLoginSuccess(user, token, refreshToken);
      } else {
        onLogoutSuccess();
      }
    }, (error) => {
      onError(error)
    });

    handleRedirectResult();
  }, [])
```

`onLogoutSuccess()` is triggering because `user` is null.

PS: I spammed a bunch of alerts in there because I'm struggling to debug on my device, those aren't in my production build.

Comment: Ran in to a similar issue myself just recently. Earlier `signInWithRedirect` worked fine for both Google and FB in my webapp but lately it hasn't been working for Google and it's not easy to find the cause. Just in case it helps you forward.. in my case it works on Chrome desktop but not on ios (neither Chrome nor Safari) and not in Safari desktop either. When failing the `getRedirectResult` result is null. If I replace `signInWithRedirect` with `signInWithPopup` it works 100% but then I have to live with the drawbacks of using a popup.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'll have to try the popup flow again. Last I tried it, it worked on desktop, but I believe on iOS (both chrome and safari) the popup was being blocked or immediately closed.

Comment: Yes, if you have blocked popups in the browser it won't work, I guess that's why Google recommends signInWithRedirect, but since they can't get it to work consistently I've opted to use signInWithPopup and for those users with blocked popups, they have to use an email/password registration. Still haven't checked if I can detect if popups are blocked somehow and then prompt the user about this, but that would be great of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just received an email from Google Cloud about this issue. The reason this failure is happening is because my auth domain did not match my custom domain. Many new clients are not allowing 3rd party cookies, which breaks this flow. The fix is to set up your auth domain to match your custom domain.

I had two steps to do this (you may have more if you have not set up your custom domain yet)

1. update your firebase auth config's `authDomain` value to your custom domain.
2. Update your OAuth 2.0 Client ID Credential in the API's and Services console to include your new custom domain in the redirect url's section, so add `https://yourcustomdomain/__/auth/handler`. Note: this is different than the authorized domains in the identity providers console!